# tp-link m3750 4g lte router won't boot

Tags: boot, router, modem

All of a sudden my router just won't start up, devices can't discover the router and it just says "tp-link" on the small screen, I tried the reset button but it doesn't seem to be working. I'd appreciate some help

Comment: Try doing a hard reset of the modem:  https://www.tp-link.com/ca/support/faq/497/?utm_medium=select-local

Comment: @John sorry my friend but I don't think this model has a hard reset I looked everywhere but I can't find anything but the regular reset button

Comment: Then I am not certain. Remove the device from any power source for about an hour. Then try the regular reset again to see if that brings it back to factory settings